# tkinter freezing with pywinauto import

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, freeze, pywinauto

**Issue:**
My python gui (tkinter) is freezing when I click a button that runs:
`filename = filedialog.askdirectory()` 
This *only* happens when I have `from pywinauto import application` in another script.  If I comment out the pywinauto import, askdirectory works just fine.  No freezing, the window pops up as expected.  I do not see any errors when this happens.

Sorry for the long post btw, I wanted to provide as much detail as possible.  Let me know if more is needed and what it is you're looking for.  I would ideally like to use askdirectory, but I've thought that I could maybe just use askopenfilename and get the directory off of that.

**Python version:**
Python 3.4.4

**Windows version:**
Windows Server 2012 R2 (Can't change this)

**Things I've tried:** 
1. Basic Threading via tutorials (still froze every time, code example at bottom) 
2. Commenting out sections of code to narrow problem down. 
3. Tried going through with PyCharms debugger, but if there is an error, I'm not seeing it.
4. Different IDE.

IDLE = fail

Pycharm = fail(same interpreter as idle from what I can tell, so no surprise)

Pythonwin = works just fine)

**Code blocks below:**
I have put the code blocks below in order of how they interact if you will.  It starts at the first one, then goes to the second(middle) one, which finally goes to the third.

**Questions:**
Is there a way for me to check for an error?
Have I done something wrong here that is causing this to happen?
Why would askopenfilename work fine but not askdirectory?

**File containing the window that freezes:**

```
from InstallMenu import MainMenu
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

"""
This is where it freezes.  If I change askdirectory to openaskfilename it 
works without any issues.  If I comment out the from pywinauto import 
application from opusite.py, askdirectory works without issue.
"""
def chooseInstallFolder(installFolderPath):
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    installFolderPath.config(text=filename)

def submitFolder(installFolderApp, installFolderPath, setObj):
    installFolderApp.destroy()
    MainMenu(installFolderPath, setObj)

def chooseInstall(setObj):
    installFolderApp = Tk()
    installFolderApp.title("Find Install Folder")
    installFolderApp.geometry("300x200")

    #Gui items
    pickAFolder = Label(installFolderApp, text = "Select your Install Folder")
    pickInstallerButton = Button(installFolderApp, text="Browse", command = lambda : chooseInstallFolder(installFolderPath))
    installFolderPath = Label(installFolderApp, text = " ")
    submit = Button(installFolderApp, text="Submit", command = lambda : submitFolder(installFolderApp, installFolderPath, setObj))

    #Packing
    pickAFolder.pack()
    installFolderPath.pack()
    pickInstallerButton.pack()
    submit.pack()

    installFolderApp.mainloop()
```

**The menu script the submit button above goes to:**
I have iParcPro commented out because it uses the same import causing the freeze.

```
import opusite
#from iParcPro import *
from Sql import *
from tkinter import *

def OPUSiteInstall(installFolderPath):
    opusite.OPUSiteInstall(installFolderPath, setObj)
    opusite.rs485Install(installFolderPath, setObj)

def MainMenu(installFolderPath, setObj):
    menuWindow = Tk()
    menuWindow.title("Auto Installer Menu")
    menuWindow.geometry("325x250")

    #Create variables
    ChooseAButton = Label(menuWindow, text = "Choose an option")

    OPUSiteButton = Button(menuWindow, text="OPUSite Install", height = 1, 
    width 
    = 15, command = lambda : OPUSiteInstall(installFolderPath, setObj))

    #Pack
    ChooseAButton.pack()
    OPUSiteButton.pack()

    menuWindow.mainloop()
```

**Code containing the import that seems to freeze this:**

```
import pyautogui as ag
"""
This import here freezes it.  If I comment out just the import, the 
askdirectory works fine.
"""
from pywinauto import application

def OPUSiteInstall(installFolderPath, setObj):
    path = installFolderPath + '\\OPUSite\\AMI.OPUSite.Setup.msi'
    app = application.Application().Start(r'msiexec.exe /i ' + path)
    Wizard = app['OPUSite Setup']
    Wizard.NextButton.Wait('enabled', 50000)
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard['I &accept the terms in the License 
    Agreement'].Wait('enabled').CheckByClick()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    ag.typewrite(setObj.databaseName)
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.press('space')
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.typewrite(setObj.password)
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.typewrite(setObj.password)
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.typewrite(setObj.password)
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.Install.Click()

    Wizard.Finish.Wait('visible', 50000)
    Wizard.Finish.Click()

def rs485Install(installFolderPath, setObj):
    path = installFolderPath + '\\OPUSite\\AMI.RS485AdapterSvc.Setup.msi'
    app = application.Application().Start(r'msiexec.exe /i ' + path)
    Wizard = app['RS485Adapter Setup']
    Wizard.NextButton.Wait('enabled', 50000)
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard['I &accept the terms in the License 
    Agreement'].Wait('enabled').CheckByClick()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.Install.Click()

    Wizard.Finish.Wait('visible', 50000)
    Wizard.Finish.Click()
```

**This is the threading thing I tried.  It didn't work:**

```
from InstallMenu import MainMenu
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading

def chooseInstallFolder(installFolderPath):
    def callback(installFolderPath):
        filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
        installFolderPath.config(text=filename)
    t = threading.Thread(target=callback, args=(installFolderPath,))
    t.start()

def submitFolder(installFolderApp, installFolderPath, setObj):
    installFolderApp.destroy()
    MainMenu(installFolderPath, setObj)

def chooseInstall(setObj):
    installFolderApp = Tk()
    installFolderApp.title("Find Install Folder")
    installFolderApp.geometry("300x200")

    #Gui items
    pickAFolder = Label(installFolderApp, text = "Select your Install 
    Folder")
    pickInstallerButton = Button(installFolderApp, text="Browse", command = 
    lambda : chooseInstallFolder(installFolderPath))
    installFolderPath = Label(installFolderApp, text = " ")
    submit = Button(installFolderApp, text="Submit", command = lambda : 
    submitFolder(installFolderApp, installFolderPath, setObj))

    #Packing
    pickAFolder.pack()
    installFolderPath.pack()
    pickInstallerButton.pack()
    submit.pack()

    installFolderApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `import sys; sys.coinit_flags = 0` before `from pywinauto import Application`. It allows multithreading for COM objects using `comtypes` package.

Comment: I added your suggestion right before, so this is what it looks like now. 
`import pyautogui as ag
import sys; sys.coinit_flags = 0
from pywinauto import application
`

My chooseInstallFolder is setup like the threading example from my original post.  I am still encountering the same freezing problem.

Comment: OK, maybe this is fundamental threading issue because Python is single threaded and threads run separating by time. True parallel threading is possible using new async/await syntax in Python 3.5+.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get past this problem.  I want to point out that I'm still not sure why this worked.  All I did was move the pywinauto import into my functions and now the askdirectory is working fine.

```
import pyautogui as ag

def OPUSiteInstall(installFolderPath, setObj):
    from pywinauto import application
    path = installFolderPath + '\\OPUSite\\AMI.OPUSite.Setup.msi'
    app = application.Application().Start(r'msiexec.exe /i ' + path)
    Wizard = app['OPUSite Setup']
    Wizard.NextButton.Wait('enabled', 50000)
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard['I &accept the terms in the License 
    Agreement'].Wait('enabled').CheckByClick()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    ag.typewrite(setObj.databaseName)
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.press('space')
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.typewrite(setObj.password)
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.typewrite(setObj.password)
    ag.press('tab')
    ag.typewrite(setObj.password)
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.Install.Click()

    Wizard.Finish.Wait('visible', 50000)
    Wizard.Finish.Click()

def rs485Install(installFolderPath, setObj):
    from pywinauto import application
    path = installFolderPath + '\\OPUSite\\AMI.RS485AdapterSvc.Setup.msi'
    app = application.Application().Start(r'msiexec.exe /i ' + path)
    Wizard = app['RS485Adapter Setup']
    Wizard.NextButton.Wait('enabled', 50000)
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard['I &accept the terms in the License 
    Agreement'].Wait('enabled').CheckByClick()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.NextButton.Click()
    Wizard.Install.Click()

    Wizard.Finish.Wait('visible', 50000)
    Wizard.Finish.Click()
`
```

Answer (score 2):

met the same issue, and found solution below

https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/517
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html#com-threading-model

```py
import sys
sys.coinit_flags = 2  # COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED
import pywinauto
```